# How to show that $S \wedge T, S \vee T, S + T$ are stopping times?

Tags: probability, self-study, optimal-stopping, measure-theory

From Williams (1991) *Probability with Martingales*:

[image]

1. $$(S \wedge T \le n) = (S \le n) \cup (T \le n) \in \mathscr F_n$$

$$\because (S \le n), (T \le n) \in \mathscr F_n$$

2. $$(S \ \vee \ T \le n) = (S \le n) \cap (T \le n) \in \mathscr F_n$$

$$\because (S \le n), (T \le n) \in \mathscr F_n$$

3. $$(S + T = n) = (S = k) \cap (T = n - k) \in \mathscr F_n$$

where $k \in [0,n]$:

$$\because (S = k) \in \mathscr F_k \subseteq \mathscr F_n, (T = n - k) \in \mathscr F_{n-k} \subseteq \mathscr F_n$$

---

Is that right?

Comment: Looks good to me overall, but I'd suggest two changes. For one, you could clarify that your filtrations are closed under intersections and unions. Second, you should be taking unions over different values of $k$.

Comment: @eric_kernfeld What do you mean by the second? Thanks

Comment: $(S + T = n) = \cup_{k \in 0, 1, ... n} (S = k \text { and } T = n - k)$. Your proof lacks the union over all possible values of $k$.

Comment: @eric_kernfeld Post as answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting as answer after suggesting this initially via comments:

Looks good to me overall, but I'd suggest two changes. For one, you could clarify that your filtrations are closed under intersections and unions, which you use without stating. Second, you should be taking a union over different values of $k$:

$(S + T = n) = \bigcup\limits_{k=0}^n (S = k \text { and } T = n - k)$, which is not the same as $(S = k \text { and } T = n - k)$ for some fixed $k$.

Comment: "you could clarify that your filtrations are closed under intersections and unions" Actually this is part of the definitions hence stressing this point seems rather misleading.